# Laravel db transaction half condition

Tags: database, laravel, transactions

Hi i found some bug in my laravel app and wondering how to fix it :/

My controlers code

```
public function patvirtinimas($id,$bookid)
{
    return \View::make('grazintiknyga.patvirtinti',compact('id','bookid'));
}
public function grazintiknygasave($id,$bookid,Request $request)
{

    if(Input::get('taip'))
    {   
        $grazinimas = Carbon::now();
        $grazinimas->format("Y-m-d");
        $kasprieme = Auth::user()->id;
        $resetas = NULL;
        //dd($kasprieme);

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            DB::table('borrows')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['grazinimo_data' => $grazinimas,
                      'prieme' => $kasprieme
            ]);
            DB::table('books')
            ->where('id', $bookid)
            ->update(['isdavimo_data' => $resetas,
                  'terminas' => $resetas,
                  'grazinimo_data' => $resetas 
            ]);

        DB::commit();
        // jeigu viskas gerai
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        dd($e);
        // jeigu kazkas negerai
        }

        return \Redirect::to(url('grazinti-knyga'))->with('grazinta','Knyga grąžinta sėkmingai!');
    }
    elseif(Input::get('ne'))
    {
        return \Redirect::to(url('grazinti-knyga'))->with('negrazinta','Knygos grąžinimas atšauktas!');
    }
}
```

One function for viewing other for updating tables in db

routes

```
Route::get('patvirtinti-grazinima-{id}-{bookid}', 'BorrowController@patvirtinimas');
Route::post('grazinimas-save-{id}-{bookid}', 'BorrowController@grazintiknygasave');
```

The problem is when i edit route directly in my browser grazinimas-save-{someid}-{somebookid}

When one of parameters matches other dont then half of db transaction works and
other doesn't update and  destroys my db :? can some one help fix this bugs ? that both parameters must match in db to update. Maybe there is some parameters hidding and validation?

Comment: I assume your ids are not being recognized in your controller. Does it work if you use `/` instead of `-` in your route?  `'patvirtinti-grazinima/{id}/{bookid}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slashes `/` are the expected way to separate arguments in your routes.
Your parameters are not getting passed on properly to your Controller.

Changes the routes to the following (if you can)

```
Route::get('patvirtinti-grazinima/{id}/{bookid}', 'BorrowController@patvirtinimas');
Route::post('grazinimas-save/{id}/{bookid}', 'BorrowController@grazintiknygasave');
```

Another option is to handle the logic in your Controller or a Middleware (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-dash-instead-of-slash-in-routes)